# HTML display an icon as submit button

Tags: html, css

I'm making a project for school, but I'm stuck on this problem:
I want an input submit, but instead of the button I want an icon to click on.
I have not figured it out yet after searching for other answers.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-icon">
</form>
```

Comment: What icon do you want to use? Do you have a link to it? Have you tried `background-image: url(path/to/image.png)`?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have tried background-image: url(path), but it resulted in the image not showing properly. I want to use a search icon.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9xyfy0gk/

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use input, try this:

```
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: <left|right>;
padding-<left|right>: <width of image>px;
```

It's usually a little easier to use a button with an img inside:

```
<button type="submit"><img> Text</button>
```